# Devise registration controller conflict with my own "registrations" controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I'm in a bit of a pickle here as I have used Daniel Kehoe's excellent Rails Composer to build a small app. I'm also using Devise for authentication.

I had the bright idea to create a "registrations" controller/model to enable my users to register to different classes they want to attend. Obviously, this is wrecking havoc in my app and I'd like to know what is the best way to get out of this said pickle :)

I'm left with two choices and would like to have you Rails experts chime in:

1. Rename my registrations controller and leave Devise alone (I'm guessing this is better in the long run if Devise is updated etc..)
2. Change how the Devise routes are named in the config/routes.rb file.

What change should I plan on doing?

Thanks for your help!

Francis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your registrations controller in a module/namespace.

```
Classroom::RegistrationsController
end
```

Then make sure the views of the registrations controller are inside a directory of classroom.

```
-views
--classroom
---registrations
----new.html.erb
```

In your routes.rb, put the regsitration routes in a namespace.

```
namespace :classroom do
 resources :registrations
end
```

Comment: Hi @John, thanks for your reply. Will this affect the relations between my registrations model and the other models?

Comment: It shouldn't effect your models. You can namespace your registrations model just like the controller above, but you probably don't need to unless you want to do it for consistency.